# Conteúdo em Carrossel prejudica SEO? O conteúdo do Carousel que está oculto é indexado?

Tags: html, css, navegador-de-internet, seo, web-crawler

Estou com uma dúvida com relação ao Carrossel e **como o conteúdo dele é indexado ou não pelos *crawlers* de busca**.

Primeiramente, acredito que a maioria dos Carousel não são tão amigáveis do ponto de vista da **Acessibilidade**. Isso por si só já poderia prejudicar a indexação do conteúdo. Tirando esse problema de acesso ao conteúdo oculto, ainda tem a questão da indexação desse conteúdo que não está visível na tela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Repare que nesse modelo apenas um slide fica visível por vez, os outros 3 slides estão ocultos, e são eles que me preocupam...

**Então ficaram as dúvidas.**

- Os crawlers de buscas conseguem indexar o conteúdo total de um Carrossel ou apenas o primeiro slide?
- Do ponto de vista do SEO vale a pena usar esse tipo de "componente"?

Answer (score 1):

Estive lendo este artigo a um tempo atrás pois tive a mesma dúvida :
https://www.workhorsemkt.com/pros-and-cons-content-carousels/

> Por sua natureza, os carrosséis exigem o carregamento de imagens e scripts adicionais para atingir seu objetivo. Como o desempenho do site (velocidade de carregamento) é uma experiência chave do usuário, e métrica de SEO, cada segundo conta. O uso de uma única imagem estática acompanhada de texto HTML, ao invés de várias imagens, e os scripts necessários para executar um carrossel,  sempre terão um melhor desempenho.
>   Em particular, os carrosséis usam uma largura de banda preciosa em dispositivos móveis em conexões mais lentas. Também encontramos frequentemente “carrossel creep”, uma situação em que os gerentes de conteúdo continuam adicionando mais e mais slides sem remover os antigos vencidos.

Além disso o artigo mostra que há sim problemas no SEO ao usar Carrossel :

> Frequentemente, o componente textual de um carrossel é incorporado ao slide da imagem em um carrossel. Isso significa que um bot de pesquisa não pode ler e entender o conteúdo e a hierarquia do conteúdo da imagem. Embora você possa (e deva) sempre adicionar texto alternativo (alt) a uma imagem, essa solução é menos do que ideal. Espera-se que o texto alternativo da imagem descreva aquela imagem, NÃO substituindo o conteúdo HTML. Por exemplo, no conteúdo HTML, você pode ter cabeçalhos, listas, formatação (negrito, itálico), etc ... Nada disso é suportado pelo texto alternativo. Portanto, os mecanismos de pesquisa (e os deficientes visuais) podem ter dificuldade em entender a estrutura e o conteúdo do slide.

Na matéria também tem várias dicas acerca deste tema, além do resumo que coloquei aqui, vale a pena dar uma olhada !

Comment: O conteúdo é interessante mesmo, e até levantou um ponto que eu não tinha pensado, que é o carregamento da página, onde os scripts podem influenciar na performance da página o que poderia prejudicar ux e muito provavelmente o seo tb.

Comment: Sim, o SEO é afetado diretamente pela performance da página